# Cstheory meetup at SODA?

Tags: discussion

Anyone going to Kyoto next week? How about a Cstheory meetup there? I'll be there for the 3 days of SODA, not analco/anelex. I happen to live near Kyoto, in Nara. So I know the place a little bit. We can have some beers or japanese sake and discuss theory. Or if you like we can try to go to some izakaya.

Comment: Alas, I'm not at SODa, but I hope others meet up with you !

Comment: The only user I've met here was Ryan williams

Comment: Oops.  I should've checked meta this week; I was here.  Hsien-Chih Chang was here, too.